# jQuery Validate Duplicated Error Messages / Appending Lists of Error Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've scoured all recent posts over jQuery Validate's errorPlacement, wrapper, errorContainer, errorLabelContainer.

From my understanding, if I want to **SELECTIVELY** list (not all) errors in a specific field, errorPlacement is my go to method.

End goal is to display each error below it's corresponding input (default behavior), in an errorContainer at the top of my markup, and to list only related 'birthdate' errors in an errorContainer placed after the birthdate fieldset (or just appended after the #year input).

Currently experimenting with errorPlacement which appends errors to ONE of the fields I'm targeting.  However from reading a lot of [Sparky's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky) posts on JQV, using append breaks the native hide/show of errors and I end up with a lot of duplicated error messages in my markup.  Using innerHtml/html only lists one error at time based on blurred focus of inputs.

^ That's my current dilemma.

(Bonus mission: I'm not sure if I'm using grouped rules/error messages/required_from_group correctly)

HTML:

```
<!-- PROFILE INPUTS -->
<h2>Profile</h2>

<fieldset>
  <legend class="hidden">Profile</legend>
  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input id="firstname" class="form-input" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="" autofocus>

  <label for="middleInitial">Middle Initial <span class="grey-tip">(optional)</span></label>
  <input class="form-input mi" type="text" name="middleInitial" id="middleInitial" placeholder="MI" value="">

  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
  <input id="lastname" class="form-input" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="">

  <label for="gender">Select a Gender</label>
  <select id="gender" class="form-input select-gender" name="gender" type="text">
    <option value="Select a Gender" disabled selected>Select a Gender</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Nonbinary">Non Binary</option>
    <option value="Other">Prefer not to say</option>
  </select>

  <fieldset id="birthdate">
    <legend>Birthdate <span class="grey-tip">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></legend>
    <label for="month" class="hidden">Month</label>
    <input id="month" class="form-input bd" name="month" type="number" placeholder="mm" value="">

    <label for="day" class="hidden">Day</label>
    <input id="day" class="form-input bd" name="day" type="number" placeholder="dd" value="">

    <label for="year" class="hidden">Year</label>
    <input id="year" class="form-input bd" name="year" type="number" placeholder="yyyy" value="">
  </fieldset>

  <div class="birthdate-error-container"></div>

  <label for="ssn" class="label-ssn">Social Security Number</label>
  <input id="ssn" class="form-input" name="ssn" type="tel" placeholder="xxx-xx-xxxx">

  <label for="ssnCapture" class="hidden">SSN</label>
  <input id="ssnCapture" class="hidden" type="text">

  <label for="alternateId" class="label-ssn">Alternate ID <span class="grey-tip">(optional)&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a id="alternateTip" href="#">What is this?</a></label>

  <div class="more-info-box alternateId hidden">
    <p>If you do not have or do not wish to provide your Social Security Number, you may choose an alternate number for identification. First enter any 9-digit number in the Social Security Number field. You can then create an alternate ID of no more
      than 15 characters with any numbers or letters of your choosing.</p>
  </div>

  <input id="alternateId" class="form-input" name="alternateId" type="text" placeholder="Alternate ID" value="">
</fieldset>

<!-- FOOTER: NEXT BUTTON -->
<footer>
  <div class="bottom-nav">
    <a href="#" id="backToQuote">Back to Qoute</a>
    <input type="submit" id="nextButton" class="btn multi-btn primary inline-block" value="Next" form="personal_form">
  </div>
</footer>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var errContainer    = $('.error-container'),
         bd_errContainer = $('.birthdate-error-container');
    var voptions = {
        debug : "true",
        rules : {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            gender: "required",
            month: {
                require_from_group: [3, '.bd']
            },
            day: {
                require_from_group: [3, '.bd']
            },
            year: {
                require_from_group: [3, '.bd']
            },
            ssn: "required",

        },
        groups: {
            birthdate: "month day year"
        },
        messages : {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            gender: "Please make a selection",
            month: "Please enter valid month (1-12)",
            day: "Please enter valid day (1-31)",
            year: "Please enter a valid year in yyyy format",
            birthdate: {
                require_from_group: "Please fully complete month, day, and year"
            },
            ssn: "Please enter a valid SSN"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "month" || element.attr("name") == "day" || element.attr("name") == "year") {
                console.log("date group if fired");
                bd_errContainer.html(error);
                errContainer.html(error);
                // error.appendTo(bd_errContainer);
                // error.appendTo(errContainer);
            } else {
                console.log("outer if fired");
                errContainer.html(error);
                // error.appendTo(errContainer);
            }
        }
    };

    //DEVONLY (JQUERY VALIDATE PROTOTYPING):
    $('#personal_form').validate(voptions);
}
```

Fiddle (that might not work, posted over https here at the office currently):
https://jsfiddle.net/jnurbina/58u7fcqx/

Comment: Your post is confusing.  Please explain the ultimate end-goal, rather than all the little dilemmas you've been facing.

Comment: YES I was hoping you would reply.

Comment: @Sparky So the end goal is rendering error messages properly in 3 places:
1. errorLabelContainer at the top of the form
2. in a container beneath the #year input or just appended after the input element (only the birthdate related error messages #month, #year, #day [reason being - as these inputs are styled inline with eachother thus if their rendered error messages do the same; they will overlap.  I need them to stack after the #year element or in a container after the #birthdate fieldset])
3. beneath each input (default) (excluding birthdate)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 11/30/2016:**

Came up with a simpler cleaner solution.  Discovered I could use "showErrors" method in conjunction with "errorPlacement" & "success" to achieve what I was looking for.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170848/form-validate-with-jquery-use-both-errorplacement-and-showerrors) SO article helped guide me in the direction for that.

**MY JS:**

```
//Element JQ selects
    var $ec = $('.error-container'),
        $bdec  = $('.bd-error-container');

    //JQV Parameters
    var voptions = {
        debug: "true",
        //DEVONLY: uncomment ignore to skip validating specific elements
        // ignore: "#firstname, #lastname, #gender, #ssn",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var eln = element.attr("name");
            //If inline elements append to a container below that fieldset
            //Else append below input as normal
            if (eln == "month" || eln == "day" || eln == "year") {
                $bdec.append(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            var emel;
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            //For every error message in errorMap array
            //Create a string <label> element with corresponding 'class' and 'for' attr's
            //If label already exists in error-container replace it with itself
            //Else append a new errorLabel to error-container
            for(var em in errorMap) {
                emel = '<label class="error '+em+'-error" for="'+em+'">'+errorMap[em]+'</label>';
                if ($ec.find('.error.'+em+'-error').length >= 1) {
                    $ec.find('.error.'+em+'-error').replaceWith(emel);
                } else {
                    $ec.append(emel);
                }
            }
        },
        success: function(label) {
            var ecls = '.'+label.attr('id'),
                dtch = $ec.find(ecls);
            /* Clear errors from error-container since JQV only shows/hides errors below the input:
            - First check if any errorLabels exist
            - If they do, they are removed from DOM */
            if (dtch) {
                dtch.detach();
            }
        },
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            gender: "required",
            month: {
                required: true,
                range: [01, 12],
                minlength: 2
            },
            day: {
                required: true,
                range: [01, 31],
                minlength: 2
            },
            year: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            ssn: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            gender: "Please make a selection",
            month: {
                required: "Please enter valid month (1-12)",
                minlength: "Please enter month in mm format"
            },
            day: {
                required: "Please enter valid day (1-31)",
                minlength: "Please enter day in dd format"
            },
            year: {
                required: "Please enter a valid year",
                minlength: "Please enter a valid year in yyyy format"
            },
            ssn: "Please enter a valid SSN"
        }
    };

    //DEVONLY (JQUERY VALIDATE PROTOTYPING):
    $('#personal_form').validate(voptions);
```

Comment: I was too busy to dig into this yesterday but I'll review your answer and post my own if necessary.

Comment: Not knowing why you have these needs, nothing jumps out here as problematic.

Comment: @Sparky the problem was sprouted from the fact that the #month #day #year inputs are designed to be styled inline with eachother in our app.  They have fixed widths, which are shorter than the length of error messages.  So if any of those inputs triggered errors, the error messages would append below those elements and overlap each other.  Therein the task to append those specific inputs' error messages to a container outside of the birthdate fieldset was created.

Comment: @Sparky

ugh just realized an obvious mistake, my swapping functions in errorsPlacement only fire after the initial submit, so when the error messages update themselves it actually doesn't translate across to the other errorLabelContainer.  

Got more digging to do.

Comment: @Sparky see new edit.  You seem like you know all the ins n outs of JQV;  would appreciate if could point out anything I'm using improperly.